# What is the fastest technique to find complex roots of a function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, roots

I have the following function:
$$ay^6+by^3+c=0$$
It can be re-written in the quadratic form:
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

In my case, $a=1, b=-7, c=-8$; then the quadratic equation equals $(x-8)(x+1)$, therefore, the real roots are $x_1=8$ and $x_2=-1$.

**But what is the fastest or simplest way to find complex roots?**

> Considering the theorem of complex numbers' trigonometric form:
>   $$z^n=r^n(cos(n\phi)+isin(n\phi)),$$  where $z$ is a complex number,
>   $r$ is the radius and $n$ is the degree; there must be $n$ (in our
>   case $n=6$) roots totally.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

*These are the complex solutions below. How can I calculate them without using computer?

[Complex roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbII7.png)

Comment: Don't think there is an analytical way to do this for a general degree - Galois proved that there is no solution in radicals above $n=5$ for real-valued polynomials...

Comment: Yes, but it's a special type that you can re-write as a quadratic equation. I am looking for how to find the real and complex roots. I think I should start with the trigonometric form, but I cannot see the connection clearly between that theorem and the complex roots.

Comment: Are you sure $a=0$? Looks like $a = 1$ from the way you wrote your factored quadratic

Comment: Sorry, you are right graydad.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the equation in $x$ is quadratic and you found both solutions. So now, you must solve $y^3 = 8$ and $y^3 = -1$.

Start with $y = re^{ia}$ so $y^3 = r^3 e^{i (3a)}$ and find $r$ for both equations and then find the angles. Update your answer or comment here and I will be glad to help further if needed.

Comment: Yes, I think this will be that I'm looking for. Thank you, please help further.

Comment: @ÜbelYildmar so what are correct values of $r$ in each case? To find the angle note that $e^{0i} = 1 = e^{2k\pi i}$ for all integer $k$. So which values of $a$ will satisfy $3a = 2k\pi$?

Comment: In DEG:
$k=0  \rightarrow a=0°$,
$k=1  \rightarrow a=120°$,
$k=2  \rightarrow a=240°$;
$k=4$ is the same as $k=1$.